# index 4 is out of bounds for 4 length

Tags: java, arrays, z-index, indexoutofboundsexception, bounds

```
package dsa450;

import java.util.*;

public class countInversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of Array");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the size of Array");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        int p=arr.length;
        int temp[]=new int[n];
        int ans=mergeSort(arr,temp,0,n-1);
        System.out.println(ans);

    }

    static int mergeSort(int[] arr,int[]temp,int l,int r) {
         int inv=0;
         int mid;
        if (l<r) {
        
            mid=(l+r)/2;
            inv+= mergeSort(arr,temp,l, mid);
            inv+= mergeSort(arr,temp,mid+1,r);
            inv+= merge(arr,temp,l,mid+1,r);
        }
           return inv;
    }

    private static int merge(int []arr,int []temp,int l,int mid,int r) {
        
           
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        int swap=0;
        while(i<=mid-1 && j<=r) {
            if(arr[i]<=arr[j]) {
                temp[k++]=arr[i++];
                
            }
            else {
                temp[k++]=arr[j++];
                swap+=(mid-i);
            }
        }
        while(i<=mid-1) {
            temp[k++]=arr[i++];
            
        }
        
        while(j<=r) {
            temp[k++]=arr[j++];
            
        }
        
        for(i=l;i<=r;i++) {
            arr[i]=temp[i];
        }
        
        return swap;
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b8wD.png)

this is my code I am trying to solve it for 5 hours but I am not getting what is the problem can anybody help. I check resources also but the code is the same as a source but it is not running.

Comment: Hint: are you sure that `int i=0; int j=0; int k=0;` are right initial values? What if you want to merge other sections of array, not the beginning of it? Note that left portion is indexed from `l` to `mid-1` and right portion is indexed from `mid` to `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

0. The actual error is that you are attempting to get an array element 1 position beyond the end of the array.  (Array indexes go from `0` to `array.length - 1`.)
1. Use the line numbers in the stacktrace to work out exactly which line of your code the exception occurs on.  It is happening in an array indexing operation in the `merge` method.  There are 6 lines where that could be happening.
2. Add some trace prints to print out the values of critical variables at key points in the `merge` method; e.g. what `l`, `r` and `mid` are, and what `i`, `j` and `k` are.
3. Run the modified code, look at the values output by the trace prints, and try to *visualize* what the code is doing.
4. Spot where and why you are going beyond the end of an array ... and figure out what you need to change.

Answer (score -1):

Your `merge` method is failing because you are not validating `k` against size of `temp` array.

I am suggesting below small modifications in your `merge` method which will give you correct answer:

```
while (i <= mid - 1 && j <= r && k<temp.length) {
            if (arr[i] <= arr[j] ) {
                temp[k++] = arr[i++];

            } else {
                temp[k++] = arr[j++];
                swap += (mid - i);
            }
        }
        while (i <= mid - 1 && k < temp.length) {
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];

        }

        while (j <= r && k < temp.length) {
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];

        }
```

Comment: For now you are trying to escape from cause of *real problem*. Note that `k` should always be smaller than `tmp.length` since `tmp` has same size as `arr`.